# Docker port has unwanted port declaration

Tags: docker

I am using Docker latest version, here is the output of "docker version"

```
docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: 1.0.14
 Version:           20.10.6
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.3
 Git commit:        370c289
 Built:             Fri Apr  9 22:46:57 2021
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.6
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       8728dd2
  Built:            Fri Apr  9 22:44:56 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.4
  GitCommit:        05f951a3781f4f2c1911b05e61c160e9c30eaa8e
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc93
  GitCommit:        12644e614e25b05da6fd08a38ffa0cfe1903fdec
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

I run a simple python flask images as followed https://docs.docker.com/language/python/build-images/

```
docker run --publish 5000:5000 python-docker-test
```

My container has up and run without any problem. The problem is I observed an addition port declaration as below

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
8e8188fe2db3   python-docker-test   "python3 -m flask ru…"   4 seconds ago   Up 3 seconds   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, :::5000->5000/tcp   test_docker_python-docker-test_1
```

Or more specifically:

```
PORTS                                      
0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, :::5000->5000/tcp
```

Output of docker port command

```
~$ docker port test_docker_python-docker-test_1 5000
0.0.0.0:5000
:::5000
```

Question is: Why do we have such **:::5000** or generally **:::<port_num>**? Can we avoid this ?

Problem that I have is my bash script that fetch the output `docker port` need to be modified a bit. It's not a big deal. I just curious if there are some update in Docker 20.10.3.

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0.0.0.0` is the wildcard address in IPv4.

`::` is the wildcard address of IPv6.

Docker does it so that it can receive requests from both IPv4 and IPv6 network interfaces.

---

To only bind port in the IPv4 interface, you have to specify the network interface explicitly.

```sh
docker run --publish 0.0.0.0:5000:5000 python-docker-test
```

[Docker doc about networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

Comment: Thanks for explaination. But even I have completely disable IPv6 on host machine, docker still trying to expose ipv. Do we know why ?

Comment: I think Docker listens to both IPv4 and IPv6 wildcard unconditionally by default. It allows someone to add new network interface (IPv4 or IPv6) without Docker having to republish all the ports. The new interface will just work.